# Getting the namespace for an edmx in a T4 template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-generation, t4

When I install my template into a different namespace than the edmx's namespace the code that is generated has errors because of the missing namespace.

So I'm trying to add a "using" statement to solve this problem, but I don't know how to get the namespace the edmx is in.

I have this so far (edited for brevity):

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
<#@ output extension=".cs"#>

const string edmxFile = @"../Entities/NorthwindEntities.edmx";

CodeGenerationTools code = new CodeGenerationTools(this);

string namespaceName = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();
string edmxNamespaceName = "???";

using System;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using <#= edmxNamespaceName #>;

namespace <#= namespaceName #>
{
    // ...
}
```

please help me solve for "edmxNamespaceName".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MetadataLoader class

```
<#
string edmxFile = @"../Entities/NorthwindEntities.edmx";
CodeGenerationTools code = new CodeGenerationTools(this);

MetadataLoader loader = new MetadataLoader(this);
string modelNamespace = loader.GetModelNamespace(edmxFile);
#>

using System;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using <#=code.Escape(modelNamespace)#>;
```

Comment: Ok, this results in "NorthwindModel", which is listed as the Namespace in the Properties dialog, but I need the actual namespace the Data Context and Models are in.  In my example  it should be "MyProject.Entities".

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but since I stumbled upon it looking for an answer, I'll provide what I found... the properties of the *.tt includes an option called "Custom Tool Namespace".  This will override the use of the MetadataLoader which looks at the phyical structure to determine the namespace.  I had to set this for both the .Context.tt and .tt files for my old database first project.

Credit to this responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856399/changing-namespaces-in-entity-framework) that put me on the right path.