# The type or namespace name "..." could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I'm new and I don't know other way to explain so I posted my screenshot of project! Please help me to fix these errors... [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxpZS.png)

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be having a lot of problems with references and namespaces use.

First of all, you do not have a `Card` class defined. You only have a `CardModel`. Replace `Card` for `CardModel` and you will be good to go. Also, it seems you do not have a namespace declared on your class. Declare a namespace so you can use other classes in the same namespace (tipically the project name).

Second, if you are trying to use clases in another folder, you probably have to add the reference with the `using` keyword.

Comment: its not the problem only in the Card class  ! as you can see there are the same problems for Product, ProductType and WebShopEntities !!  So I should change all of them ?!

Comment: All te problems are related to the same. You have namespaces issue. You seem to be needing to read some basic c# documentation before continuing with your develpment.

Comment: @Toni If you didn't declare a namespace in one file, then I am willing to bet you didn't declare the namespace in every file, so you need to add namespace declaration to all your CS files and where you need to reference one in another, add the namespace as a using directive.

Comment: If he can't see the `WebShopEntities` class, it's quite possible that the `Card` class is defined via the edmx. In other words, maybe your edmx has the namespace issue

Comment: @SteveG what namespaces should I add and where ?!

Comment: @Andrew so what should I add ?

Comment: @Toni http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856399/changing-namespaces-in-entity-framework

Comment: @SteveG I can't find properties on .tt files !!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing probably several using directives. Every class you write should be inside a 'namespace' You declare it after your using directives but before you start writing your classes, like this:

```
namespace WebShop.CardModel {
    public class CardModel {
        public string InsertCard(Card card){
```

And when you are working in the cardModel, unless `Card` is defined in the same namespace, you need:

```
using WebShop.Card;
```

Or whatever namespace you put Card in, that's what is throwing probably 99% of your errors, it is definitely the cause of all but one of the ones in the errors we can see in your screenshot.

Comment: tried this one but doesn't work.. or maybe I wrote in the wrong section...

Comment: @Toni Well where did you even define the `Card` class?

Comment: I haven't defined Card class ! I have done this from tutorial, maybe that's why there are a lot of probs... what about this ?! http://imgur.com/mQyNGKM

Comment: Yup, well if you're trying to reference something that was never even defined, there's a big part of your issue.